# Update start urls at scrapinghub hosted Scrapy project via API call

Tags: python, api, scrapy, scrapinghub

My Scrapy spider is hosted at scrapinghub. It is managed via run spider API call.
The only thing that changes in spider from call to call is a list of start urls. The list may vary from 100 urls to couple thousand. What is the best way to update start urls in this scenario?
From what I see there is no direct option in SH API for this. 
I am thinking of updating MySql with list of urls and once updated send simple Run job API call. (Start urls will be generated from MySql table).
Any comments on such solution or other options?

My current setup is as follows.

```
def __init__(self, startUrls, *args, **kwargs):

    self.keywords = ['sales','advertise','contact','about','policy','terms','feedback','support','faq']

    self.startUrls = startUrls

    self.startUrls = json.loads(self.startUrls)

    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def start_requests(self):

    for url in self.startUrls:

        yield Request(url=url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to scrapy spider and read them inside your spider.

Send list of URLs encoded as JSON and then decode them, and now fire requests.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, startUrls, *args, **kwargs):

        self.startUrls = startUrls

        self.startUrls = json.loads(self.startUrls)

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def start_requests(self):

        for url in self.startUrls:

            yield Request(url=url ... )
```

And here is how you run send this parameter to your spider.

```
curl -u APIKEY: https://app.scrapinghub.com/api/run.json -d project=PROJECT -d spider=SPIDER -d startUrls="JSON_ARRAY_OF_LINKS_HERE"
```

Your `scrapinghub.yml` file should be like this

```
projects:
  default: 160868
```

Comment: Thank you. This whould work perfectly for a list of 10 urls. But how do I deal with 1000 urls?

Comment: what whould the keys in urls array be ?

Comment: @BillyJhon just create a list/array of URLs in whatever programming language you are using, and then encode it as JSON .. the encoded JSON will look like this ... http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=256353f25851ab72ef689ece443dd071 ... in PHP, create an array of URLs, and then do `json_encode($array)` ...

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Marked your answer as accepted one.

Comment: Hey. I am getting this error when shub deploy. Error: Deploy failed (400):
project: non_field_errors. Have added the code into original post.

Comment: @BillyJhon Show me your `scrapinghub.yml` and `requirements.txt` file

Comment: project: 252665. And there is no requirements txt for this one.

Comment: @BillyJhon See my edited answer, that is how your scrapinghub.yml file should look like

Comment: Hmm not sure whats going on ... please try to remove `project.egg-info/` & `build/` folders

Comment: Did it twice before every change.

Comment: I dont have further knowledge .. try `shub logout` and then again `shub login` ... and then deploy ... if that doesnt work too, try to update your `shub` by `pip install shub --upgrade`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158252/discussion-between-billy-jhon-and-umair).

Comment: Just for reference: `yield Request(url=url ... )` returned `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I just removed the 3 dots and got it working.

Comment: @Linkmichiel dots were just for explanation of more code follows, they were not part of Python code